# How to represent multiple object input edges into one Action node and make diagram readable?

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram, staruml

I want to create activity diagram for information system that I have programmed.

Thing is, I have many functions that accept 3-5 input arguments and it is important for me to show them on activity diagram. How can I do that?

If I represent function as an action node, how do I represent 3-5 input edges and still make diagram readable?

Comment: Would it be possible to share (part of) your "unreadable" activity diagram, so we can help make it readable?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if your system is *complicated*, the model will be *complicated*, there is no way around it (unless a birds eye view suffices for your needs).

However, a diagram is *not* the model. You can choose to display only the information *relevant* for the viewpoint of the *reader*. For example you could hide all the Object Flows and only display the Pins. A good tool will then mark the Input and Output Pins with small arrows to indicate their nature.

You could also have a *convention* that all Output Pins are implicitly connected the one Input Pin with the same name and Type. Of course this convention should be clear to all readers of the diagram and the model should still include all Object Flows. Then you only need to show Object Flows, when the connection is ambiguous.

Finally you could *combine* the Types of the multiple Pins into one structured Class and thereby reduce the number of Input Pins to one per action. This could also help to find more meaningful *abstractions*. Of course this only works, when all Object Flows are originating from the same Action.